# Dynamically draw lines with SkiaSharp in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, skiasharp

I'm trying to dynamically draw lines by using the package SkiaSharp.

I've defined the control in my xaml like this:

```
<skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasView" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
```

This is my code behind class:

```
private SkiaSharp.SKCanvas canvas;
private SkiaSharp.SKSurface surface;

void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    surface = args.Surface;
    canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();
    SkiaSharp.SKPaint thinLinePaint = new SkiaSharp.SKPaint
    {
        Style = SkiaSharp.SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        Color = SkiaSharp.SKColors.Blue,
        StrokeWidth = 6
    };
    canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, thinLinePaint);
}
```

The part above works fine, and a blue line will be drawn when loading the view at startup. But what I want to do is to dynamically draw new lines and remove the old ones.

```
public void DrawNewLine()
{
    canvas.Clear();
    SkiaSharp.SKPaint thickLinePaint = new SkiaSharp.SKPaint
    {
        Style = SkiaSharp.SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        Color = SkiaSharp.SKColors.Red,
        StrokeWidth = 16
    };
    canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, thickLinePaint);
}
```

I am using the canvas field that was declared before, but it's not working. Application will crash at runtime when using the canvas object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you manage to get your problem working?

Comment: Yes, I have marked the correct answer! @CostasAletrari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use SKCanvasView.InvalidateSurface() method to recall OnCanvasViewPaintSurface() internally.

Comment: The `SKSurface` and `SkCanvas` objects are temporary and only live as long as the paint method is executing.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, i want to redraw the canvas on a button click. Do you have any sample code to show how the InvalidateSurface works with the redraw?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/integration